# Allow public Read in S3 bucket is same as allowing to download content of bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've made an S3 bucket public with:

```
  BucketPolicy:
    Type: "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy"
    Properties:
      Bucket:
        Ref: Bucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - "s3:GetObject"
            Effect: "Allow"
            Resource:
              Fn::Join:  ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", Ref: "Bucket", "/*"]]
            Principal:
              AWS: "*"
            Sid: "AllowPublicRead"
```

Now I have a public bucket from which the objects can be accessed by a public URL. 
Now I try to download the whole content of the bucket locally:

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket .
```

This also works. Is it normal I can just download the whole content of this bucket? I know I made it public but it's more to share some objects instead of download the whole bucket.

I would think I need something more with listobject or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) requires AWS credentials to operate. It is not possible to use the AWS CLI as an anonymous user.

Therefore, when you run `aws s3 sync`, it is actually using the Access Key and Secret Key that you previous stored. These credentials identify your IAM User, so it is using the permissions from that IAM User rather than accessing your S3 content anonymously (publicly).

In fact, the `aws s3 sync` command cannot work with only `GetObject` access because it also needs to list the contents of the bucket to discover what files exist. Thus, it is clearly not using the Bucket Policy that you have defined.

To answer your question... based on the above policy, it is *not* possible for somebody to download your whole bucket because they **cannot list the contents of the bucket**. They can only access objects that they know exist.